# How to pass a value from one controller to another controller? -angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting a value from a function in `controller1`. I want to set this value to `controller2`'s directive's template. I am confused on how to use scope in this to achieve the same.

**Html**

```
<body ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller="parentcontroller as ctrl">
    <div class ="boardcanvas" style ="overflow-x:auto;"> 
        <div id = "board">
           <list-wrapper ng-repeat="task in ctrl.tasks track by $index" class ="listwrapper" id = "listwrapper"></list-wrapper>

            <add-list-controls class = "controls" tasks ="ctrl.tasks" ng-show ="ctrl.listcontrolarea"></add-list-controls>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller1 and its Directive:**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('listController', ['$scope','$compile','$http', function($scope, $compile, $http){
    'ngInject';

    $scope.tasks=[];
    $scope.cardarr =[]; 

    vm.addme = function(){
         console.log(vm);
         console.log($scope.tasks);
         $scope.tasks.push({title: $scope.title, cardarr: []});   
}
}])
.directive('addListControls', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // Element directive'
        controller: 'listController as listctrl2',
        scope: { tasks: "=",
                 cardarr: "="},
        template: `<textarea ng-model= "listctrl2.title" placeholder ="Add a List" id="input" style = "position:absolute"></textarea>
        <button id="controlbutton"  class ="btn btn success" style = "position:absolute" ng-click="listctrl2.addme()">Save
        </button>`,

};
});
```

**Controller2 and its Directive:**

```
.controller('listWrapperController', ['$scope','$compile','$http', function($scope, $compile, $http){
    'ngInject';

     $scope.tasks=[];

}])

.directive('listWrapper', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E', // Element directive
        scope:{
            tasks: '='
        },  
        controller: 'listWrapperController as listctrl',
        template: `<div id="titlebox">
        <b class ="card1" tasks="listctrl.task" id ="cardtitle">
            {{task.title}} // set the value from controller1 here
        </b>
    </div> `
};
});
```

Comment: Use factory or service to share  data between two controllers.

Comment: I am new to angular. Can you please guide me through my code on this? As I really need help

Comment: Is there no solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initalizing the  `$scope.tasks` array on both controllersand this override the original `$scope.task` reference (`ctrl.tasks`) that is set by directive definititon.

Try comment or initialize only if `undefined`

```
$scope.tasks= $scope.tasks || [];
$scope.cardarr = $scope.cardarr || [];
```

The listWrapper directive must be changed andd translate the `ng-repeat` to its template:

**HTML**

```
<list-wrapper tasks="ctrl.tasks"></list-wrapper>
```

**listWrapper directive**

```
  (...)
 .directive('listWrapper', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'E', // Element directive
        scope:{
            tasks: '='
        },  
        controller: 'listWrapperController as listctrl',
        template: 
         `<div id="titlebox" ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index" class ="listwrapper" id = "listwrapper">
        <b class ="card1" id ="cardtitle">
            {{task.title}} // set the value from controller1 here
        </b>
    </div> `
};
});
```

Comment: the error is gone but its still not displaying in the `<b>` tag